# jQuery / AJAX send content of changed divs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this CRUD system where a customer should be able to specify the amount of the desired product. When the amount is > 0, I add a new class "active" to that table row.

When the "continue" button is clicked, the rows containing a value of 0 are filtered out. After clicking the "order" button I want to send an email to the admin containing the list of desired products and the corresponding amount.

The code below works, however, the email sent contains only one field (it must be able to handle several of them) and the amount is always 0.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="email.php">
    <input type="text" class="sendmail" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
    <input type="text" class="sendmail" name="email" placeholder="Your email" />
</form>    


<table>
    <tr class='".$row['id']."'>
        <td class='name'>".$row['name']."</td>
        <td class='category'></td>
        <td class='price'>€".$row['price']."</td>
        <td class='unit'>per&nbsp;".$row['unit']."</td>
        <td class='actions'><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' value='0' id='".$row['id']."'></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="order"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Volgende</button>
<button id="confirm"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bestellen</button>
```

---

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if(parseInt(this.value) > 0){
            $('.'+id).addClass('active');
        }

        else {
            $('.'+id).removeClass('active');
        }
});

    $('#order').click(function() {

        $("#order").hide();
        $("#confirm").show();

        $('.heading').html('<i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Overzicht');
        $('tr').not(document.getElementsByClassName('active')).empty();
        $(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#confirm').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'email.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'message': $('.active').html(),
                'email':   $('[name="email"]').val(),
                'name':    $('[name="name"]').val()
        },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('You data has been successfully e-mailed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

email.php

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Subject";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';


 $body = '
     <html>
     <head>
         <title>Email: '. $email .'</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <p>From: '. $name .'</p>
      <div>
        '. $content .'
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

---

This is the email I receive:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been testing your code. 
The first thing I noticed, you are using the **".active"** class to reference several elements, which is fine because then you can call them as an array, but using $('.active').html() only returns the first element and NOT the outerhtml for the **TR**. And you also need the **TABLE** tags for your mail to have a correct html.
So I would do something like this:

```
 $(function() {
    $('#confirm').click(function(e) {
        var data = "<table>";
        $('.active').each(function(i, obj) {
            data += obj.outerHTML;
        });
        data += "</table>";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'email.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'message': data,
                'email':   $('[name="email"]').val(),
                'name':    $('[name="name"]').val()
        },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('You data has been successfully e-mailed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And then when you want to reference the HTML itself to use in the mail maybe you should delete the input and paste the value of the input instead. Because the actual value of the input may not be copied:

```
    $('#order').click(function() {

        $("#order").hide();
        $("#confirm").show();

        $('.heading').html('<i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Overzicht');
        $('tr').not(document.getElementsByClassName('active')).empty();
        //$(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $(':input[type="number"]').each(function(i,obj){
            obj.after( obj.value );
            obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
        });
    });
```

Here are the sinppets:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if(parseInt(this.value) > 0){
            $('.'+id).addClass('active');
        }

        else {
            $('.'+id).removeClass('active');
        }
 });

    $('#order').click(function() {

        $("#order").hide();
        $("#confirm").show();

        $('.heading').html('<i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Overzicht');
        $('tr').not(document.getElementsByClassName('active')).empty();
        //$(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $(':input[type="number"]').each(function(i,obj){
         obj.after( obj.value );
         obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
        });
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#confirm').click(function(e) {
     var data = "<table>";
     $('.active').each(function(i, obj) {
      data += obj.outerHTML;
  });
     data += "</table>";     
  console.log(data);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

 <table>
     <tr class='1'>
         <td class='name'>lala</td>
         <td class='category'></td>
         <td class='price'>€125</td>
         <td class='unit'>por&nbsp;kilo</td>
         <td class='actions'><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' value='0' id='1'></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class='2'>
         <td class='name'>lele</td>
         <td class='category'></td>
         <td class='price'>€225</td>
         <td class='unit'>por&nbsp;kilo</td>
         <td class='actions'><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' value='0' id='2'></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class='3'>
         <td class='name'>lili</td>
         <td class='category'></td>
         <td class='price'>€325</td>
         <td class='unit'>por&nbsp;kilo</td>
         <td class='actions'><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' value='0' id='3'></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class='4'>
         <td class='name'>lolo</td>
         <td class='category'></td>
         <td class='price'>€425</td>
         <td class='unit'>por&nbsp;kilo</td>
         <td class='actions'><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' value='0' id='4'></td>
     </tr>
 </table>

 <button id="order"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ORDER</button>
 <button id="confirm" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CONFIRM</button>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Hope I can help

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when your are dealing with input `type=number` you have to update it's `attr` value manually. Then, according to [doc](https://api.jquery.com/html/), if you are using jquery `html()` method against array it takes first element and return it's html. So, in your case you have to do few changes:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('active', parseInt(this.value) > 0);
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val()); // manually set attr value
  });

  $('#order').on('click', function() {
    $("#order").hide();
    $("#confirm").show();
    $('.heading').html('<i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Overzicht');
    $('tr').not('.active').empty();
    $(':input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', true);
  });

  $('#confirm').click(function(e) {
 let messages = [];
 $('.active').each(function(el){
     messages.push($(this).html());
    });
    console.log(messages); // composed messages array
    $.ajax({
      url: 'email.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'message': messages,
        'email': $('[name="email"]').val(),
        'name': $('[name="name"]').val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert('You data has been successfully e-mailed');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post" action="email.php">
  <input type="text" class="sendmail" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
  <input type="text" class="sendmail" name="email" placeholder="Your email" />
</form>


<table>
  <tr class='class1'>
    <td class='name'>name</td>
    <td class='category'></td>
    <td class='price'>€10</td>
    <td class='unit'>per&nbsp;1</td>
    <td><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' id='class1'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='class2'>
    <td class='name'>name</td>
    <td class='category'></td>
    <td class='price'>€10</td>
    <td class='unit'>per&nbsp;1</td>
    <td><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' id='class2'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='class3'>
    <td class='name'>name</td>
    <td class='category'></td>
    <td class='price'>€10</td>
    <td class='unit'>per&nbsp;1</td>
    <td><input type='number' name='amount[]' min='0' id='class3'></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="order"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Volgende</button>
<button id="confirm"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bestellen</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your code works fine in the console, however in the body of the email, I only get "Array".